# How to reduce duplication in Twig template

Tags: twig

I have an if/else condition in a twig template which switches the out tag of a block of code, however the inner block is the same. Is there a way to reduce the duplication without creating a separate file?
This is what I have at the moment:

```
{% if condition %}
    <a href="">
        {{ content }}
    </a>
{% else %}
    <span>
        {{ content }}
    </span>
{% endif %}
```

I was hoping to do something such as:

```
{% if condition %}
    <a href="">
        {% include mycontent %}
    </a>
{% else %}
    <span>
        {% include mycontent %}
    </span>
{% endif %}

{% mycontent %}
    {{ content }}
{% endmycontent %}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Place `{{ content }}` in the file `content.twig.html` and change to `{% include "content.twig.html" %}`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an extra file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use extra files you could use macro's :

```
{% import _self as macro %}

{% macro foo(content) %}
    {{ content }}
{% endmacro %}

{% for condition in [0, 1, 0, 1, ] %}
    {% if condition %}
        <a href="">{{ macro.foo('Bar') }}</a>
    {% else %}
        <span>{{ macro.foo('Bar') }}</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/0ux0s4)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do has to be done using the normal syntax. an extra file. and include this file.

But if u want to do this without extra file. use the {% set variablecontent = "put content here" %} and then in your "{% mycontent %}" part u put {{ variablecontent  }}

hope this helps

Comment: That would work for a smaller piece of content, but my content is slightly larger. Thanks though.

Comment: @Votemike thought so